# Remove all active filters from workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear all filters on multiple Pivot tables within the workbook (on multiple worksheets). I have tried the following but can't get anything to work.

I'm relatively new to VBA FYI.

```
Sub ClearFiltersAttempt1()
   For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   For Each xTable In xWs.PivotTables
       xPivotField.ClearAllFilters
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 `For Each` statements are missing the closing statement `Next`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClearFiltersAttempt2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.ClearAllFilters
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

`Option Explicit` and proper code indentation will help you determine syntax errors and missing variable declarations

Comment: Thank you very much!
That works perfectly. However.. I'm now being given a 1004 error "A pivot table report cannot overlap a table or XML mapping"

I have checked and there are no tables overlapping.. any idea?

Comment: To get more details about the problem: add the variable `pt` to the **Watches** window (right-click it and select "Add Watch...". Now run the code until you get the 1004 error. When it stops the `pt.ClearAllFilters` line should be highlighted in yellow. In the Watches window scroll down to the property **Name** - this will tell you name of the pivot table that is overlapping; after that try to identify the pt in question against any other table or XML mapping